# How to avoid listing dependencies twice when packaging with Conan?

Tags: c++, dependency-management, conan

I'm currently trying to package a project as a Conan package. This project manages its dependencies with Conan itself already and as such has a `conanfile.txt` which lists its dependencies. I'm doing it in-repo following [how the documentation suggests doing it](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/package_repo.html).

Now I would like to package this project but I can't figure out what the proper way to simply let that `conanfile.txt` be the reference for the project's dependencies, and if it's possible to leverage the fact that it's already there instead of re-listing all the dependencies in the `conanfile.py`. I could skip it by just removing the `conanfile.txt` and [using the `conanfile.py` as a consumer](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/mastering/conanfile_py.html), but that forces a more complex handling of the actual `build()` step in the recipe which I would like to avoid. I would also like to let the people that develop the library be able to build it the way they would prefer, not necessarily through Conan except for the dependency management.

Is there a way to fetch a project dependencies from within the Conan recipe instead of listing twice the dependencies, both in the `conanfile.txt` and in the `requires` variable of the Conan recipe? If possible I would like to avoid reading the `conanfile.txt` and manually feeding line by line the dependencies into the `requires` variable.

I'm aware that I might be looking for a way that doesn't fit Conan's design and/or how packaging should work in general.

Comment: If you are building your project with cmake, you can list all your dependencies in your `conanfile.py`. When you build your project with cmake it will take only the dependencies and skip `build()` step. Exactly as you would pass the `conanfile.txt` to your cmake. This approach lets you to avoid having dependencies listed twice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `conanfile.txt`, but I strongly recommend using `conanfile.py` instead.
You can run `conan install .` as well, and install all dependencies listed in the `conanfile.py`. As the command `install` will not run your `build()` section, I can't see the problem.

Anyway, you can create a base class in `conanfile.py` which loads the `conanfile.txt` content and filter the requirements. Oblivious, it sounds be more complex than using only `conanfile.py`.

In terms of feature, there is no way, Conan doesn't load both files. By default it will `conanfile.py` and ignores `conanfile.txt`. You can't force both by argument or variables.

Comment: You didn't say otherwise, but for clarity you _can_ use either the .txt or .py explicity (`conan install ../conanfile.txt`) when both are present.